# Get ffmpeg version number

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to get the version number from ffmpeg in a reliable way, hopefully without parsing a string.

I can parse the output of `ffmpeg -version`, however i see no guarantee that string won't change in the near future.

```
$ ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
[...]
```

I'm interested in a slightly more programmatic way to get the version number, like maybe telling ffmpeg to output JSON instead or just the version number without me having to extract it from a body of text.

Answer (score 5):

If you have the companion `ffprobe` tool, you can run

```
ffprobe -v 0 -of default=nw=1:nk=1 -show_program_version | head -1
```

which will print just the version string.

e,g,

```
N-100221-g18befac5da
```

You can also emit JSON.

```
ffprobe -v 0 -of json
```

gives

```
{
    "program_version": {
        "version": "N-100221-g18befac5da",
        ...
    }
}
```

The `ffmpeg` binary itself doesn't provide these outputs.

Note that the version string format and composition can vary - it's not standardized and can have custom strings added by the builder. But in general, a git build will have a commit hash (with or without the `g` prefix) and a release build will have a sequence of the form `x.y.z`. See my Windows builds for a couple of examples of other forms - I include the commit date as well.

The `N` count in my example above is the commit count of the master branch from when the binary was built.

Comment: Thank's for this but i simply can't assume ffprobe will exist alongside ffmpeg and their versions will be the same. At best this is speculative.

Comment: You're out of luck then as ffmpeg doesn't emit self-contained version string. It would be unusual for ffprobe to be from a different build.

Comment: It is what it is. Thanks for your answer, your approach is probably the best precision one you can get right now.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54364073/117259), this should work:

```
ffmpeg -version | sed -n "s/ffmpeg version \([-0-9.]*\).*/\1/p;"
```

Tested on FFmpeg as installed via Homebrew on macOS and I get the following output:

```
4.3.1
```

---

And after reviewing the helpful feedback left in the comments below, I think this might be a better future-proof solution:

```
ffmpeg -version | awk -F 'ffmpeg version' '{print $2}' | awk 'NR==1{print $1}'
```

The reason being is the Sed command above is mainly looking for a `major`.`minor`.`patch` version number and that would exclude non-traditional version numbers like the nightly build format of `N-100221-g18befac5da` and such.

This can be tested by running this command that outputs `4.3.1`:

```
echo 'ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers' | awk -F 'ffmpeg version' '{print $2}' | awk 'NR==1{print $1}'
```

And this command that deals with those nightly build “numbers”; it will output `N-100221-g18befac5da`:

```
echo 'ffmpeg version N-100221-g18befac5da Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers' | awk -F 'ffmpeg version' '{print $2}' | awk 'NR==1{print $1}'
```

So until FFmpeg allows for a clean output of the version number directly from the binary itself, some command line scraping seems to be the best way to go… For now!

Comment: But i explicitly asked not to parse strings that may change in the future.

Comment: @evilSnobu Fair enough. But in my experience with command line tools, things like basic version number output formatting rarely changes. Your choice but this is a method many people use for many tools; not just FFmpeg.

Comment: Also this won't match nightly builds like `N-100221-g18befac5da`. Not trying to be dismissive, i appreciate your answer but hope is not really a strategy.

Comment: `awk` would be better than `sed` here and would get the "nightly" builds too.

Comment: The criticisms here are quite helpful. While I do regularly use FFmpeg for basic purposes, I was not aware of how the nightly build version numbering differed from the basic/numeric `major`.`minor`.`patch` format many are used to. So taking a hint from @llogan I have come up with a new Awk-based method that should work. And the original poster is 100% right; this all seems a bit much to get such basic info. Perhaps opening a ticket with the FFmpeg development team requesting something more direct to extract the version number would be in order? Anyway, hope this helps in some way!